# On a expression from W. Rindler special relativity's book

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames

In Wolfgang Rindler's book on special relativity I am asking help to understand the step that he get the conclusion that $dx/dt =$ constant in the forth row from bottom to top, the statement is in the following image:

[image]

In the preceding paragraph concerning the doubt he states that the defining particles in S' (that I think it is particles at rest relative to S') are moving with constant velocity in S. That said, for me $dx'/dt'$ should be zero. What am i missing? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? In the book, the expression dx/dt=const. is derived. dx'/dt' is zero because x_i=const but the book doesn't say otherwise.

Comment: In the forth row, from bottom to top, how one gets dt=A_00dt' and dx_i=A_i0dt'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation between the coordinates in the two inertial systems is
$x_\mu = \sum_\nu A_{\mu \nu} x'_\nu + B_\mu$ where $x_0=t$, $B_\mu$ a constant and $\nu, \mu = {0,1,2,3} $.

Looking at the zero component on the left-hand side:

$t= x_0 = \sum_\nu A_{0 \nu} x'_\nu + B_0 = A_{0 0} x'_0 + \sum_i A_{0 i} x'_i + B_0$ where $i={1,2,3}$.

Taking the total differential of this gives $dt = dx_0 = A_{00} dx'_0 = A_{00} dt'$ because the $dx'_i = 0$ since $x'_i = const.$ and the same for $B_0$.

The same can be done for the $i$th component on the lhs:

$x_i = \sum_\nu A_{i \nu} x'_\nu + B_i = A_{i 0} x'_0 + \sum_j A_{i j} x'_j + B_i$

Taking again the total differential on both sides we have

$dx_i = A_{i0} dx'_0 = A_{i0} dt'$

Dividing the two results yields

$dx_i/dt = (A_{i0} dt')/(A_{00} dt') = A_{i0}/A_{00} = const.$